# Is regularization required with overdetermined data

Tags: estimation, least-squares, regularization

I'm doing least squares estimation on large set of data and I started to wonder whether I should regularize my OLS estimator. My professor told me that this isn't necessary, because the data is overdetermined. Could someone explain to me why? Why isn't regularization required with overdetermined data?

Thnx for any help! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regularized regression problem is most often applied when the matrix inversion is ill-conditioned, i.e. the matrix is nearly singular. So this is the property you need to concern yourself with when considering regularization. This comes into play very often in the case of colinear regressors. That said, both overdetermined and underdetermined systems can be ill-conditioned so the fact that your matrix is overdetermined does not necessarily preclude the need for regularization.

Now assuming the matrix is invertible, overdetermined systems do indeed have an OLS estimator but it is approximate. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system#Approximate_solutions). The $QR$ factorization improves the situation; see [here](http://glowingpython.blogspot.ca/2012/03/solving-overdetermined-systems-with-qr.html).